# Using materialize css .col divs to create (should not follow row line) to make something like in the following picture

Tags: html, css, materialize

I am using Materialize css to make blog . And finding difficult to create something with the materialize grid columns.
See the desc below...

My html code is like this.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col l6 m12 s12">
    <div class="my-content">
      -----FIRST-content-goes-here-----
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col l6 m12 s12">
    <div class="my-content">
      -----SECOND-content-goes-here-----
    </div>
  </div>
</div> <!--row -->
```

Ignoring the css part , the image below denotes how this worked:

[image: see problem picture here]

But i want the (.l6) columns to be created like as in the this picture:

[image: see solution needed picture]

I think the CSS plays a role for those divs positions and any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @chiitranjan I'm added an answer below ,don't forget to tick it if it's useful :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use can do that easily using **CSS3 flexbox** .

I'm added an snippet below.

```css
.col{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  }
.box{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:gray;
  border:1px solid #000;
  }
.parent{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  }
.diff{
  height:200px;
  }
.one{
  height:70px;
  }
.three{
  height:30px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="parent"> 
    <div class="col">
      <div class="box">
      </div>
      <div class="box">
      </div>
      <div class="box">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col dif">
      <div class="box one">
      </div>
      <div class="box diff">
      </div>
      <div class="box three">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```